# Error in p4v when using 'reconcile offline work', "Unintelligible revision specification '\...#have'."

Tags: perforce, p4v

When I try to use 'reconcile offline work' on a directory ending with '\C#\' in the p4v client on windows, I get that error.

Does it have something to do the with the '#' in the path? Is there any workaround that doesn't involved renaming the directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perforce workaround to add files with '@'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952591/perforce-workaround-to-add-files-with)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because of the # character which denotes a revision number (e.g. path_to_file#3 denotes revision 3).  I don't think there's any way to escape the character in P4V, so you'll have to rename the directory.