# Perforce workaround to add files with '@'

Tags: perforce

By [design](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/p4guide/03_using.html), Perforce does not allow filenames with wildcards `@#%*` be added. It is giving this error:

```
Can't add filenames with wildcards [@#%*] in them.
Use -f option to force add.
```

However, I have SASS files that have `@` on them to support mixins.  For example:

```
carbon-fibre-@2X.png
sprite-dashboard-@2X.png
```

What is the best **workaround** to have these files added to Perforce, with most minimal disruption on checkin, checkout, compile, build, and deploy flow ?

Comment: You mean, something other than the '-f' flag mentioned in the error message?

Comment: If I use `-f` flag, it will treat @ as revision isnt it ? Thus disrupt the `sync` function. Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a more recent version? I test it, and find it warns on first add, but does not require any special handling.

Comment: I'll add some more info about -f as an explicit answer.

Comment: @tkosinski, do you mean upgrading the Perforce server ?  What version do you have ? I can definitely suggest it to my admin here.

Comment: @JesonMartajaya yes, I'm running 2015.2. It looks like nearly every release since 2012 has had some sort of new wildcard fix/enhancement.

Comment: You also could consider not submitting those names to Perforce but to make your build system copy them to a temporary location using the desired names and to consume those files from there.

Answer (score 5):

You can add files with Perforce wildcard characters in them. As the 'p4 help add' page documents:

> To add files with filenames that contain wildcard characters,
>   specify the -f flag. Filenames that contain the special       characters
>   '@', '#', '%' or '*' are reformatted to encode  the characters using
>   ASCII hexadecimal representation.  After the files are added, you
>   must refer to them using the  reformatted file name, because Perforce
>   does not recognize the local filesystem name.

The requirement to uniformly refer to the filename from then on using the encoded '%40' is annoying, I agree, but it **does** work.

Here's a short example:

```
$ touch 'carbon-fiber-@2X.png'
$ p4 add 'carbon-fiber-@2X.png'
The file named 'carbon-fiber-@2X.png' contains wildcards [@#%*].
Can't add filenames with wildcards [@#%*] in them.
Use -f option to force add.
$ p4 add -f 'carbon-fiber-@2X.png'
//depot/carbon-fiber-%402X.png#1 - opened for add
/path/to/carbon-fiber-@2X.png - empty, assuming text.
$ p4 submit -d added-carbon-fibre
Submitting change 2.
Locking 1 files ...
add //depot/carbon-fiber-%402X.png#1
Change 2 submitted.
$ p4 files //...
//depot/carbon-fiber-%402X.png#1 - add change 2 (text)
$ p4 fstat //depot/carbon-fiber-%402X.png
... depotFile //depot/carbon-fiber-%402X.png
... clientFile /path/to/carbon-fiber-@2X.png
... isMapped 
... headAction add
... headType text
... headTime 1466547058
... headRev 1
... headChange 2
... headModTime 1466547033
... haveRev 1
```

Comment: When retrieving this `carbon-fiber-%402X.png` file from the depot, would P4VS automatically rename this file to `carbon-fiber-@2X.png` on user local machine ?

Comment: Yes, the actual file on your laptop will be named with the `@` sign. It is just the file name as specified in arguments to `p4` commands and in the output from those commands that is encoded as `%40`

Comment: How to do this from the Perforce UI without using the command line